Old movie in the desert, a sandstorm and a guy tied to palm trees
Here in my office one of my co-workers, who is around 50 years old, has been looking for an old movie she saw when she was a child. She doesn't remember it very well and just gives us small details about it. Here they are:

The movie was in black and white. We have some doubts here because
we aren't sure if the actual movie was in B&W or if her TV set was
in B&W.
It seems to occur in the desert. At least that's the scene she
remembers, so I'm not sure if it was a small or a big part of the
movie happening in the desert.
There was a woman, who was dressed like the star of "I dream of
Jennie".
There was this man who was injured, and was being taken care of by
her.
Then, there is an scene with a sandstorm (or an hurricane, something
dangerous). I guess they don't have any shelter to save the man's
life the only thing she can do is to tie him to a palm tree.

We are not really sure if this movie exists or if she just dreamed of it. There is money running on this, so maybe you can help me identify this movie.
EDIT: 
I added the following extra info. It isn't much, but I'm following posting rules about details that could help identify movies:

She saw the movie when she was a child, but on TV, so it could have
been an   old rerun. Judging from her age, it was around the 70's.
Could be way older, from the 60's or 50's, but at least isn't more
recent than the 70's.
This is a real action movie, not an animated one.
I'm guessing this was an American movie, since european movies
weren't shown much in my country back then.

Really, if I knew the name of one the actors I could easily find what this movie is. But I don't, that's why I'm asking here to people with much more experience in movies than me.

Could this be El Topo? http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0067866/

@FranciscoV. I really doubt it. Another co-worker who saw El Topo would have recognized the movie.

There really isn't enough information here. What was the movie about? When was it set? What else happened? The fact that there is money on it doesn't make the question on topic!

Could it be Ten Tall Men? It's got Burt Lancaster and Jody Lawrance. Her outfit is kind of I Dream of Jeannie-esque.
IMDb for Ten Tall Men
http://imdb.com/rg/an_share/title/title/tt0044110/
IMDb picture of Burt Lancaster and Jody Lawrance in Ten Tall Men
http://imdb.com/media/rm1285438976/tt0044110/

That's a very good guess, I'll have to show it to my friend. I took a look at it in YouTube and found all the elements except the whole "tied to a palm tree" scene, but I'm willing to believe she could be confused about it. I'll let everybody know how it goes.

I had hoped for a mention of the palm tree/sand storm thing, too. There are stills of a man tied to a tent pole on the IMDb page, and I wondered if perhaps that image could have gotten mixed up with one of a sandstorm in your friend's memory. Memories are strange animals, after all. Regardless, please do keep us posted. I'm invested, now; I've got to know how it turns out!

It could be the 1937 movie, The Hurricane, starring Dorothy Lamour and Jon Hall, and directed by John Ford. I think she was tied to a tree in the movie.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0029030/
